# Add a column in the employee table 'hno' listing the house number of the employees. Rank the employees in order of the house number in ascending orde

Tags: sql

I would like to add a column in the employee table 'hno' listing the house number of the employees. Rank the employees in order of the house number in ascending order:

```
fname   minit   lname   ssn bdate   address sex salary  super_ssn   dno
John    B   Smith   123456789   1/9/1965    731 Fondren, Houston, TX    M   30000   333445555   5
Franklin    T   Wong    333445555   2/9/1955    638 Fondren, Houston, TX    M   40000   888665555   5
Joyce   A   English 453453453   1/9/1972    5631 Fondren, Houston, TX   F   25000   333445555   5
Ramesh  K   Narayan 666884444   1/9/1962    975 Fondren, Houston, TX    M   38000   333445555   5
James   E   Borg    888665555   1/9/1937    450 Fondren, Houston, TX    M   55000   NULL    1
Jennifer    S   Wallace 987654321   1/9/1941    21 Fondren, Houston, TX F   43000   888665555   4
Ahmad   V   Jabbar  987987987   1/9/1969    980 Fondren, Houston, TX    M   25000   987654321   4
Alicia  J   Zelaya  999887777   1/9/1968    3321 Fondren, Houston, TX   F   25000   987654321   4


alter table employee
  add hno varchar(50) default '123';



update employee
set hno = (select substring_index(address, ' ', 1) from employee where address is not null);
```

Comment: sql is query language...please mention your DBMS name like `mysql`, `sqlserver`...etc

Answer (score 0):

First create below function to get substring by index,

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SubstringIndex(
    @SourceString varchar(8000),
    @delim char(1),
    @idx int
)

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
RETURN
WITH
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),

E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),

E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),

cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@SourceString)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
),

ctePosition(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( @idx) n
    FROM cteTally
    WHERE SUBSTRING(@SourceString, n, 1) = @delim
)

SELECT LEFT( @SourceString, MAX(n) - 1) String FROM ctePosition;
go
```

Then run this,

```
update employee set employee.hno = (select String from SubstringIndex(employee.address, ' ', 1)) where employee.address is not null;
```